# Perl inheritance through ISA

Tags: perl, inheritance, package

Question regarding inheritance in Perl using @ISA:
Input -  3 files: one is a main script, two containing parent & child packages, correspondingly:

main:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use child qw(parent_or_child_function srictly_parent_function);

parent_or_child_function();
srictly_parent_function();
```

parent.pm:

```
package parent;

sub srictly_parent_function
{
    print "this is strictly parent function\n";
}

sub parent_or_child_function
{
    print "this is parent function which can be inherited\n";
}

1;
```

child.pm:

```
package child;

our @ISA = 'parent';

use Exporter qw(import);
@EXPORT_OK = qw(parent_or_child_function srictly_parent_function);

sub parent_or_child_function
{
    print "this is child function that replaced parent's\n";
}

1;
```

Output is:

```
 $main
this is child function that replaced parent's
Undefined subroutine &child::srictly_parent_function called at main line 6.
```

What am I doing wrong? I understand that child package doesn't have strictly_parent_function , but shouldn't child's @ISA package be searched for it?

Comment: Re "What am I doing wrong?", 1) Inheritance is a feature of objects, yet you have no objects. 2) You export `&child::srictly_parent_function`, yet you never define it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make parent actually an object.

```
package parent;
use strict;
use warnings;

# Constructor
sub new {
    my ($proto) = @_;
    my $class = ref($proto) || $proto;
    my $self = {};

    # Bless is what casts $self (instance of this class) as an object
    return bless($self, $class);
}

sub srictly_parent_function {
    my ($self) = @_;
    print "this is strictly parent function\n";
}

sub parent_or_child_function {
    my ($self) = @_;
    print "this is parent function which can be inherited\n";
}

1;
```

Then with parent as an object, child can inherit

```
package child;

use strict;
use warnings;

# I prefer use base, as it's safer than pushing classes into @ISA
# See http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl2/prog/ch31_03.htm)
use base qw(parent);

sub parent_or_child_function {
    my ($self) = @_;
    print "this is child function that replaced parent's\n";
}

# To give an example for accessing variables from a class.
my $variable = "WHATEVER";
sub get_variable { return $variable;}

1;
```

Then to test your code:

```
perl -e "use child; $object = child->new(); $object->parent_or_child_function();"
```

or to script it up properly;

```
# Load up child class
use child qw();

# Invoke constructor to create an instance of the class
my $object = child->new();

# Invoke function from child class
$object->parent_or_child_function();

# Get Variable
$object->get_variable();
```

Comment: Thanks you. This explains it quite comprehensively. It leads me to another question, though - what if I have a variable declared within a package? Can I access this variable through a class (package) object?

Comment: Apologies, just returned from a 4 day vacation.
You can always access any variable from the class. Just write up an public accessor for it, which returns that variable. (See amended example)